# Akka Streams - Combine different Sources

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

i have an object that builds different Flows, each flow has filters, that may can discard values, so the final result may contain a subset of the original source.
The code:

```
object RawFlowGeneratorByVehicle {

    val deviceEventFilter = (de : DeviceEvent) => de.isValidPosition : Boolean

    def buildSpeedFlow(vehicles : List[Vehicle]) : VEHICLERAWFLOW = {
        Flow[DeviceEvent].filter(deviceEventFilter)
           .groupBy(vehicles.length,de => de.getModemId)
           .reduce((a, b) => if(a.getGenerationDate >= b.getGenerationDate) a else b)
           .mergeSubstreams
           .map(de => VehicleFlowResult(de.getModemId,"Speed",de.getSpeed))
    }

   def buildCountFlow(vehicles: List[Vehicle], maxSpeed : Double) : VEHICLERAWFLOW = {
        Flow[DeviceEvent].filter(deviceEventFilter)
          .groupBy(vehicles.length,de => de.getModemId)
          .filter(de => de.getSpeed > maxSpeed)
          .map(_ -> 1)
          .reduce((l, r) => (l._1, l._2 + r._2))
          .mergeSubstreams
          .map(a => VehicleFlowResult(a._1.getModemId, "SpeedCount", a._2))
   }

   //...Other flows
}
```

After build the flows, merge them in a graph and the final result is a csv file , this is the object with the graph

```
object RunnableFlows {
  def rawGraph(in: Source[DeviceEvent, NotUsed], flows: List[VEHICLERAWFLOW]): Source[VehicleFlowResult, NotUsed] = {
   val g = Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
     import GraphDSL.Implicits._
     val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[DeviceEvent](flows.length))
     val merge = builder.add(Merge[VehicleFlowResult](flows.length))
     in ~> bcast ~> flows.head ~> merge
     for (curFlow <- flows.tail) {
       bcast ~> curFlow ~> merge
     }
    SourceShape(merge.out)
  })
  g
 }

}
```

the flows may have different size , so i dont know how to merge/concat/zip?, to generate a csv of the same size of rows like the vehicles list(this list dont have duplicate values),setting default values when an specific vehicle not pass the filters of the flows

The csv must be something like this

imei;name;event;value

aaa;vehicle1;Event1;100

aaa;vehicle1;Event2;100

bbb;vehicle2;DefaultEvent;defaultValue

ccc;vehicle3;Event5;89

Thanks!!

Comment: first of all I would suggest adding more info about your business task. It is not clear from the description what you are trying to archive. For example, you can specify the format of input data. Second, I guess there is some misundestanding in terminology. Flow is a part of a blueprint that can be materialized, it defines the way data is going to be transformed.